# Android retrofit with coroutines works differently in release build than in debug mode

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, kotlin-coroutines

I am in the middle of testing my Android app in release build.

What I have been testing now is,

1. Fetch data from network- 3 network requests(with Retrofit2),
2. Validate each requests,
3. Finally, insert results from 3 network requests into my local database(with Room)

The thing is, I noticed something undesirable situation in release build.

The Following screenshots are the logs I put to see the flow in both release and debug mode.

1. Debug Build

[image]

2. Release Build

[image]

When you compare logs from these two screenshots, you can see that
each log is identical until getting network results from remote server(until line 5)

However, from line 6, it becomes different, and later it shows same logs.

The point is, Why does my code behave differently in build type.

At first, I thought it was not fully understanding Coroutines and Retrofit2, So I read documents again and tried to fix it(adding and removing `withContext, launch and many others`, which didn't work.

In my perspective, The only difference between debug and release build is whether using `R8, ProGuard rules, minifyEnabled, shrinkResources as well as signing configs`.

Is there something I should do with ProGuard rules, or Does my code still have problems?

Where should I look for?

Thank you!

Here are some code snippets that are used to put logs.

```kotlin
**From ViewModel**

suspend fun fetchData() {
        Log.i("Fetching_Data", "fetchData() Starts")
        val result = repository.fetchData()
        Log.i("Fetching_Data", "fetchData() End")

        Log.i("Fetching_Data", "Fetching Result : $result")
        _fetchSucceeded.value = result
    }
```

```kotlin
**From Repository**

suspend fun fetchData(): Boolean {
        try {
            Log.i("Fetching_Data", "Fetching if not exist starts")
            fetchIfNotExist()
            Log.i("Fetching_Data", "Fetching if not exist ends")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(e)
        }

        Log.i("Fetching_Data", "Fetching if not exist returns a boolean")
        return true
    }
```

```kotlin
**From BaseRepository**

suspend fun fetchIfNotExist() {

        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {

            val companiesDeferred = async { SeoulApi.retrofitService.getAllCompanies() }
            val codesDeferred = async { SeoulApi.retrofitService.getAllCodes() }
            val summariesDeferred = async { SeoulApi.retrofitService.getAllSummaries() }

            Log.i("Fetching_Data", "Fetching companies")
            Log.i("Fetching_Data", "Fetching codes")
            Log.i("Fetching_Data", "Fetching summaries")

            val companies = companiesDeferred.await()
            val codes = codesDeferred.await()
            val summaries = summariesDeferred.await()

            if (companies.succeeded && !companies.data.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                database.companyDao().insertAll(companies.data)
                Log.i("Fetching_Data", "Network Request 1.Company Result: ${companies.succeeded}")
                Log.i("Fetching_Data", "Network Request 1.Company Size: ${companies.data.size}")
            }

            if (codes.succeeded && !codes.data.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                database.codeDao().insertAll(codes.data)
                Log.i("Fetching_Data", "Network Request 2.Code Result: ${codes.succeeded}")
                Log.i("Fetching_Data", "Network Request 2.Code Result: ${codes.data.size}")
            }

            if (summaries.succeeded && !summaries.data.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                database.annualSummaryDao().insertAll(summaries.data)
                Log.i("Fetching_Data", "Network Request 3.Summary Result: ${summaries.succeeded}")
                Log.i("Fetching_Data", "Network Request 3.Summary Result: ${summaries.data.size}")
            }

            Log.i("Fetching_Data", "Inserting into database End")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that functionality is different, it might be that the minification just removed retrofit logs in production mode?

Comment: try removing proguard/minify from the release (to isolate whether that is the source of your problem). Are you verifying with a Proxy if the network calls are being made?

Comment: @VojinPurić, Thanks for your comment! Yes it is indeed different, not a minification result that removed log.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini Thanks for your comment! The main problem was because of Code Shrinking and optimization. I checked it fetches data from remote but the problem was adapter when parsing from Json to `data` class used for entities.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be more of a help, never had this issue. Only thing that comes to my mind is to check if it is some kind of permission/networking issue. For example mby you are not permitted to use http protocol in production, or some kind of proxy/reverse-proxy issue (but proxy is very unlikely the problem since you are not getting logs, usually proxy issues let you make the call but you don't get the response back)

Comment: @VojinPurić the problem lies under parsing Json and `data class` and after release build, R8 removes my code, so I need to specify some `keep` rules.

Answer (score 2):

You might have Proguard error. If you have not already added rules for your models which is used by `retrofitService.getAllCompanies()`, `retrofitService.getAllCodes()`, `retrofitService.getAllSummaries()` add it as like below (*subpackage contains models*):

```
-keepclassmembers class my.project.package.subpackage.** {
    public synthetic <methods>;
    <fields>;
}
```

The other thing is you are not dealing with exceptions. First, i think you should catch errors everywhere you expect them to happen. Retrofit/Network error is expected here (all at once or individually):

```
try {
    val companies = companiesDeferred.await()
    val codes = codesDeferred.await()
    val summaries = summariesDeferred.await()
} catch(e:Throwable){
    // deal with it
}
```

Second, you should wrap this code in ViewModel with `try/catch`, just to make sure to catch unexpected errors finally:

```
try {
    val result = repository.fetchData()
} catch (e:Throwable){
    // deal with it
}
```

Comment: Thank you!, starting from your response, I checked, read and debug with [Official Docs regarding R8 and shrinking code and resources, and optimization](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#shrink-code). The problem lies in converting Json into `data class`  (adapter) that contains enums and others and I need to specify some `-keep` rules. Thanks again!!

Comment: For those who plan to publish apps on Google Play Store, I would highly recommend reading  [Official Docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#shrink-code)!!!